# Jsoup, ignore links with javascript popups <a href="javascript:OpenPopup()">

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to parse some pages for links and then httpclient to test the links to see if they are working. Some of the links on my pages are , I want to ignore these.

At the moment when my code tries to get the link from  it returns blank. I could exclude all blanks from my check, but sometimes there may be links created on my site that are blank(by accident) that I want to catch so I can fix.

So what I want to do is be able to identify when a link is a javascript popup so I can ignore the link test on this particular link. My code to parse for the links is as follows:

```
private void setLinks(){
    String link;
    try {
        Document doc = response.parse();

        Elements element = doc.select(htmlElementTarget+" a[href]");
        for (Element page : element){
            link = page.absUrl("href");
            if (validateUrl(link)){
                linksText.add(page.text());
                links.add(link);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Any other criticisms about my code is welcome

Comment: I want to able to identify when a link is a javascript popup, the href <a href=“javascript:OpenPopup()”> returns blank. I want to be able to check if it's a javascript popup but don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `href` is always `javascript:OpenPopup()` you could just add another if statement.

```
if (page.attr("href").equals("javascript:OpenPopup()")) {
    if (validateUrl(link) {
    }
}
```

Note... code not tested for compilation.